# javac using multiple CPU cores

Tags: java, multithreading, javac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using multiple cores/processors when compiling Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727493/using-multiple-cores-processors-when-compiling-java)

Can javac be configured to benefit from multiple CPU cores?

Comment: Most of the time is spent reading/writing to files. Not sure using multiple cores would make much difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it cannot use multiple cores; however the Eclipse compiler can, if that helps.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727493/using-multiple-cores-processors-when-compiling-java).